# jQuery traversing. Find siblings including itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery traversing to jump between DOM elements.

First of i have a onClick function:

`$(document).on('keyup', '.size, .ant', function(){`

Inside of this function I send data about what's clicked, to another function.

```
sulorTableRowWeight( $(this) );
function sulorTableRowWeight(thisobj){
```

Now, I'd like to traverse from the clicked element `$(this)` to its parent. I'd like to find the parent's siblings and then traverse down to a specific sibling.

`var inputSize = $(thisobj).parent().siblings('.sizeTd').children('.size');`

My problem is when I want to traverse back down to the element I came from, it is not listed as a sibling because it isn't a sibling...

`var inputSize = $(thisobj).parent().siblings(); console.log(inputSize)`

console will give me the siblings, but not the one U came from...

So, when a user clicks ".size" I'd like to traverse up to the parent and back to size.... When a user clicks ".ant" I'd like to traverse up to the parent and then down to ".size"...

I tried to hardcode the traversing:

`var inputSize = $(thisobj).parent().siblings('.sizeTd').children('.size');`

But it won't work because it is not actually a sibling.

So what is it? And how can I get back to it?

If it is not possible, I have to run some if/else statements, U guess...

**UPDATE**

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.size, .ant', function(){ 
  //Find changed <select> .tbody
  var tbodyId = $(this).parent().parent('tr').parent('tbody').attr('id'); 
  //Check <tbody> #id
  if(tbodyId === "cpTableBody"){
  }
  else if(tbodyId === "sulorTableBody"){ 
    sulorTableRowWeight( $(this) );
  }
  else if(tbodyId === "konturTableBody"){
    konturTableRowWeight( $(this) );
  }
  else if(tbodyId === "kantbalkTableBody"){
    kantbalkTableRowWeight( $(this) );
  }
})

//Function sulorTableRowWeight
function sulorTableRowWeight(thisobj){
    //Find the selected data-weight
    var selectedWeightmm3 = $(thisobj).parent().siblings('.selectTd').children('.select').find(':selected').data('weightmm3'); 

    //Find input .size value
    var inputSize = $(thisobj).parent().siblings('.sizeTd').children('.size'); console.log(inputSize)
```

**PROBLEM**
My var `inputSize` will return undefined when I click a ".size" element. That´m's because it is not listed as a sibling to itself.

I know it's keyup, not click...

Comment: That was a fast minus.. Tell me why please?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question right... but if you want to remember that sibling you have to store it somewhere. If the parent has multiple siblings there is no obvious way to come back to that sibling which it originally came from.

Comment: @madalinivascu And how does that explaining make sense?

Comment: didnt get your question. Can you write the entire code in one go. and may be then ask the problem that will make more sense i beleive.

Comment: why do you mean by  `when a user click ".size" i'd like to travers up to parents and back to size.... When a user click ".ant" i'd like to traverse up to parents and then down to ".size"..` why do you need to do this?

Comment: @Mjukis I would guess you got down-voted for bad formatting, put your entire code in code blocks and add comments? that might be easier.

Comment: put the code in jsfiddle

Comment: @ZiTAL i cannot.. it is to big.. it is dynamic with ajax calls.. php files.. etc

Comment: @Mjukis but the problems is in the client side in JS, you need to focus the problem and remove all the other information that is no relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

e.target will select the current input

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.size, .ant', function(e) {
  inputSize = $(e.target);
  if($(e.target).is('.ant')) {//test if the element is .ant 
  inputSize = $(e.target).parent().find('.size');//get .size based on .ant
  }
   console.log(inputSize[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input class="size x1" placeholder="x1">
  <input class="ant x1" placeholder="x1 ant">
</div>
<div>
  <input class="size x2" placeholder="x2">
  <input class="ant x2" placeholder="x2 ant">
</div>
```

Comment: Maby with this code.. but not with mine.. i cannot access the sibling ".sizeTd" because it´s where i came frome.. and it is not listed as a sibling..

Comment: updated my answer, please provide the parsed html if this doesn't help you

Comment: "e" is the event you trigger when you click .size ot .ant

Comment: [prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: input.size.input, selector: ".size input"]

Comment: Some how.. the element i'm coming from.. cannot target it self.. it is not in the list of DOM element.. I guess.. why would you start from a element and traverse from it.. and the back to it.. in the same line of code.. maby it is not possible..

Comment: why do you want to go to the parent and back to the element what value do you get in that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128695/discussion-between-madalin-ivascu-and-mjukis).

Comment: I´d like to do it.. because i dont know who/where i am.. so i go out to a place i know of.. and then back..to the place i'd like to be in.. but maby..as mentioned.. i should do it in another way.. with for ex.. and if statement..

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, if you're passing in `$(this)` as `thisObj` I don't think you need to be nesting `thisObj` in a `$()`. (See note below)

Anyway, you could try using `.parents('<grandparent>').find('<child>')` so basically you're traversing one higher level up the tree with `<grandparent>`, then getting all the descendants that match the child selector. That should include the branch of the three that `$(this)` represents. But it's hard to say for sure without seeing your HTML.

** A good practice when assigning jQuery objects to variables is to use `$` syntax, ie `var $this = $(this)` so you know anything prepended with a `$` is a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

inside `sulorTableRowWeight` , you should have the reference to the clicked element in `thisobj` variable.